# Swift Extension - Optional

Tags: swift, swift-optionals

I'm trying to extend optionals into something readable, and achieved this so far:

```
@discardableResult
    func isNotNil(_ handler: (Wrapped) -> Void) -> Optional {
        switch self {
        case .some(let value):
            handler(value)
            return self
        case .none:
            return self
        }
    }
    
    @discardableResult
    func isNil(_ handler: () -> Void) -> Optional {
        switch self {
        case .some:
            return self
        case .none:
            handler()
            return self
        }
    }
```

So that I can call my functions on an optional such as:

```
viewModel?.title.isNotNil { _ in
   //do something
}.isNil {
  //handle error
}
```

The problem is, I want to reuse these functions to return specific types, which I'm not able to achieve or am missing something out. For example:

```
let vm: MyViewModel = dataSource?.heading.isNotNil {
  return MyViewModel(title: $0.title, subtitle: $0.subtitle)
}
```

I've been brainstorming on this and would love some help around this.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you re-inventing `Optional.map`? E.g. `let vm = dataSource?.heading.map { MyViewModel(...) }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing in your example will raise errors. It boils down to

```swift
let vm: MyViewModel
if let heading = dataSource?.heading  {
   _ = MyViewModel(heading.title, heading.subtitle)
  vm = heading
}
```

So you're trying to assign `heading` to `vm` (which I am assuming are of different types) and you just construct and drop the  `MyViewModel` you construct in the closure

What would be a better option is something along these lines:

```swift
func mapOptionalOrNot<T>(notNil: (Wrapped) -> T, isNil: () -> T) -> T {
    switch self {
    case .some(let value):
        return notNil(value)
    case .none:
        return isNil()
    }
}
```

And you could of course give both function default arguments so you can leave them out.

With Swift 5.3s new multi closures you could do something like

```swift
let vm: MyViewModel = dataSource?.heading.mapOptionalOrNot { value in
    // Map if we have a value
    return MyViewModel(title: value.title, subtitle: value.subtitle)
} isNil: {
    // Map if we don't have a value
    return MyViewModel(title: "Empty", subtitle: "Empty")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Optional` is generic and has an associated type that you can use in your extensions as well. It is called `Wrapped`.

Here is some sample code that you can paste into a Playground:

```
import UIKit

extension Optional {
    @discardableResult
    func isNil(_ handler: () -> Void) -> Wrapped? { // <-- We are returning Wrapped, wich is a generic concrete type
        switch self {
        case .some:
            return self
        case .none:
            handler()
            return self
        }
    }
}

let str: String? = nil

// The function is used and the return value is assigned to the variable handled
let handled = str.isNil { 
    print("Handling nil value")
}

print(type(of: handled))
// Prints "Optional<String>
```

Please also note that that what you are trying to build already exists mostly: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map

You should probably just used Swift's map instead of your own implementation.